# Что за знак "перепись населения"?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, знаки, опрос-разработчиков

Ну, вот, вообще не интересно...

В правой части главной страницы видны получения знака "перепись населения", но он недоступен для ознакомления простым смертным.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И результат [перехода по знаку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/204/census)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за социальное расслоение? (прим. для особо чувствительных: сарказм)

Что это за знак? Кто получает?

Comment: Модераторам тоже 404, если что. Мы с народом :)

Comment: @Dmitry не подскажете, как вы нашли эту "правую часть страницы"?

Comment: @PeterKolosov на главной странице см. "Недавно полученные знаки". Но там уже другие приехали.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Аааааааа, вооооот оно что :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В профиле участника, получившего знак, можно найти подсказку:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но работает оно криво (я еще не проходил, но знак выдан). Ситуация со ссылками (и кривым поведением вообще), вероятно, вытекает [отсюда](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424491/3240681).

Баг-репорт о текущей ситуации есть на [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424593/3240681).

Comment: Ща как пройду опрос чтобы получить серебряный бейджик :D

Comment: Кстати, почему у меня не присуждается этот бейджик? Опрос я прошёл, но ничего не видно

Comment: @PeterKolosov видимо, потому что всё глючит. См. на MSO.

Comment: Не "что-то глючит", а всё вполне описано в [обновлении](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424491/updated-2023-may-8-changes-to-the-census-badge)

Comment: Тоже прошёл, правда перешёл с английского SO по ссылке, знака нет нигде

Answer (score 4):

#### С чего всё началось

Сначала бейдж просто [убрали](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424491/updated-2023-may-8-changes-to-the-census-badge), ведь это "нарушает конфиденциальность":

> Начиная с этого года, **мы больше не будем выдавать значок переписи тем, кто полностью заполнит опрос для разработчиков. Кроме того, с 4 мая 2023 года мы удалили ранее присвоенные знаки "перепись населения"**. 
> Эти действия предпринимаются **для лучшей защиты конфиденциальности тех, кто примет участие в опросе в будущем, а также конфиденциальности тех, кто заполнил предыдущие опросы**. Когда мы рассмотрели процесс опроса этого года, было установлено, что присвоение значка переписи добавляет ненужный элемент риска для конфиденциальности. Хотя мы понимаем, что это может разочаровать тех, кто потратил время на заполнение опроса, чтобы получить этот значок, ваша конфиденциальность имеет первостепенное значение.

Бессмысленное решение. Я полностью согласен с этим [ответом](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424491/updated-2023-may-8-changes-to-the-census-badge/424492#424492). Этот бейдж у пользователя только даёт знать, что... Пользователь прошёл этот опрос. И есть куча других знаков, которые тоже "раскрывают секретные данные": хотя бы знаки, связанные с голосованием.

#### Как всё есть сейчас

Администрация увидела, что народ недоволен, и решила пойти с народом на компромисс. Тем, кто получил знак раньше он будет присвоен (но только один раз, и у всех знаков будет одинаковая дата). Но новые знаки выдаваться не будут:

> В течение недели с 8 мая мы будем повторно выдавать значок переписи всем членам сообщества, которые ранее получили значок переписи. Однако в рамках нашей приверженности конфиденциальности мы внесем некоторые изменения в знак: 
> Пользователи смогут получить знак "перепись населения" только один раз. Если раньше у вас было несколько таких знаков, теперь у вас будет только один.
> Все бейджи будут иметь одинаковую дату выпуска.
> **Начиная с [опроса разработчиков 2023 года](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424565/), мы больше не будем выдавать значок переписи тем, кто пройдёт весь опрос разработчиков.**

**P.S**: переводы - отредактированные мною переводы от машинного переводчика.

Comment: То есть, я больше не смогу получить этот знак? Или ещё есть надежда?

Comment: Но тогда мне непонятно, как так другие получили этот знак...

Comment: @PeterKolosov знак больше не выдаётся, а есть он сейчас только у тех, кто заработал его раньше.

Comment: эх... Ну, ладно, будь как будет. Всё равно у меня скоро серебряный будет, а потом и золотой ;)

Comment: Перемудрили чо-то ребята

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ребята и не ищут лёгких путей ))